# Запуск сайта на сервере node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Такой вопрос. Есть сайт, запускаю его на сервере node js. Вижу его только я, нужно выложить его в интернет, проще говоря. Знаю, что для этого нужен виртуальный сервер, но не знаю какой выбрать. И как потом привязать его к домену, чтобы набрав в браузере "mysite.ru" можно было увидеть мой сайт. Это реализуемо? Если да, то как?

Comment: нужно выложить его в интернет© вам на постоянку или временно - кому-то показать и закрыть?

Comment: На постоянную основу